# Hash table, using special values to mark empty and deleted indexes

Tags: c++, performance, hash-map

The following is a program for my school. It's supposed to use a hashtable to store values/keys. We use a marking system to mark for empty indexes and deleted indexes. -1 for empty and -2 for deleted. This hashtable is an outdated concept but the real goal is to learn how to manipulate hashtables. I want to ask if this is efficient or how it could be improved, please be specific. Lastly, just take a look at the header to see what each function/how the program/code works.

**Main.cpp:**

```
using namespace std;

#include "tests.h"
#include "hashtable.h"

int main()
{
    testHashTable();
    cout << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Tests.h (used to test the code):**

```
#include "hashtable.h"

void testHashTable() {
    cout << "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^" << endl;
    cout << "Testing hashtables: " << endl;
    cout << "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^" << endl;
    cout << "Constructing a hashtable and printing: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    HashTable test(7);
    cout << test << endl;
    cout << "Capacity: " << test.getCap() << endl;
    cout << "Number of items: " << test.getNumOfItems() << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Hashtable insertion and print data: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    test.insertKey(21);
    cout << test << endl;
    test.insertKey(21);
    cout << test << endl;
    test.insertKey(7);
    test.insertKey(1991);
    test.insertKey(1992);
    test.insertKey(1996);
    test.insertKey(69);
    test.insertKey(420);
    cout << test << endl;
    cout << "Number of items: " << test.getNumOfItems() << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Searching and print: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Find 14, does it exist? " << boolalpha << test.searchKey(14) << endl;
    cout << "Find 400, does it exist? " << boolalpha << test.searchKey(400) << endl;
    cout << "Find 21, does it exist? " << boolalpha << test.searchKey(21) << endl;
    cout << "Find 1337, does it exist? " << boolalpha << test.searchKey(1337) << endl;
    cout << "Find 69, does it exist? " << boolalpha << test.searchKey(69) << endl;
    cout << "Find 420, does it exist? " << boolalpha << test.searchKey(420) << endl;
    cout << "Find 7, does it exist? " << boolalpha << test.searchKey(7) << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Deleting values in hashtable: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    test.deleteKey(21);
    test.deleteKey(69);
    test.deleteKey(420);
    test.deleteKey(1991);
    test.deleteKey(1969);
    cout << test << endl;
    cout << "Number of items: " << test.getNumOfItems() << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Hashtable insertion and print data again: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    test.insertKey(21);
    test.insertKey(69);
    cout << test << endl;
    cout << "Number of items: " << test.getNumOfItems() << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Rehash hashtable and print data again: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    test.rehash();
    cout << test << endl;
    cout << "Capacity: " << test.getCap() << endl;
    cout << "Number of items: " << test.getNumOfItems() << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Reset hashtable: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    test.resetTable();
    cout << test << endl;
    cout << "Number of items: " << test.getNumOfItems() << endl;
    cout << "Is this hashtable empty? True or false? " << boolalpha << test.isEmpty() << endl;
}
```

**Hashtables.h:**

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H 

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

const int DEFAULTCAPACITY = 23;

class HashTable
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const HashTable& theTable); // Print operator overloading.
public:
    // Constructors:
    HashTable(); // Default constructor.
    HashTable(int newCapacity); // Overloaded constructor.
    HashTable(const HashTable& otherTable); // Copy constructor.
    HashTable(HashTable&& otherTable); // Move constructor.
    // Accessors:
    int getNumOfItems() const; // Spits out the number of items stored within the hashtable.
    int getCap() const; // Spits out the capacity of the hashtable.
    bool isEmpty() const; // Spits out if the hashtable is empty or not.
    // Function(s):
    void insertKey(int value); // Inserts a value into the hashtable using the hashvalue function to get the correct index.
    void deleteKey(int value); // Deletes a value within the hashtable, setting it to -2.
    void resetTable(); // Empties out the hashtable, setting everything to -1.
    void rehash(); // Rehashes all non-deleted/non-empty values of the hashtable into a bigger hashtable that is double that of the current hashtable (next prime #).
    bool searchKey(int value) const; // Returns true if it finds the value within the hashtable.
    // Operator overloading(s):
    HashTable& operator=(const HashTable& otherTable); // Assignment operator overloading.
    HashTable& operator=(HashTable&& otherTable); // Move assignment operator overloading.
    // Destructor:
    ~HashTable(); // Destroys the hashtable.
private:
    int hashValue(int key, int j) const; // Calculates an expression to get the hashvalue so you can store the value in index.
    int* searchKey(int value, int j) const; // Spits out an index if there's one, if not spits out nullptr.
    int *ht; // Points to hashtable.
    int numOfItems; // Number of items in the hashtable.
    int capacity;   // Maximum length of the hashtable.
};

#endif
```

**Hashtables.cpp:**

```
#include "hashtable.h"

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const HashTable& theTable) {
    for (int i = 0; i < theTable.capacity; ++i) {
        out << theTable.ht[i] << " ";
    }

    return (out);
}

HashTable::HashTable() {
    capacity = DEFAULTCAPACITY;
    ht = new int[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
        ht[i] = -1;
    }

    numOfItems = 0;
}

HashTable::HashTable(int newCapacity) {
    capacity = newCapacity;
    ht = new int[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
        ht[i] = -1;
    }

    numOfItems = 0;
}

HashTable::HashTable(const HashTable& otherTable) {
    // Set all member variables of the calling object:
    capacity = otherTable.capacity;
    numOfItems = otherTable.numOfItems;

    // Create a new array:
    ht = new int[capacity];

    // Copy all elements of the array parameter onto the calling object:
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfItems; ++i) {
        ht[i] = otherTable.ht[i];
    }
}

HashTable::HashTable(HashTable&& otherTable) {
    ht = move(otherTable.ht);
    capacity = move(otherTable.capacity);
    numOfItems = move(otherTable.numOfItems);

    otherTable.ht = nullptr;
    otherTable.capacity = move(0);
    otherTable.numOfItems = move(0);
}

int HashTable::getNumOfItems() const {
    return (numOfItems);
}

int HashTable::getCap() const {
    return (capacity);
}

bool HashTable::isEmpty() const {
    return (numOfItems == 0);
}

int HashTable::hashValue(int key, int j) const {
    const int stepSize = 3;

    return ( ((key)+(j*stepSize)) % capacity ); // Space for readability.
}

void HashTable::insertKey(int value) {
    if (numOfItems < capacity) {
        bool foundSlot = false;
        int j = 0;

        int* indexValue;
        while (!foundSlot) { 
            indexValue = &ht[hashValue(value, j)];

            if (*indexValue == -1 || *indexValue == -2 || *indexValue == value) {
                if (*indexValue != value) {
                    *indexValue = value;
                    ++numOfItems;
                }

                foundSlot = true;
            }

            ++j; // Just increase the j...
        }
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Capacity in HashTable has been reached, cannot exceed the capacity." << endl;
    }
}

void HashTable::deleteKey(int value) {
    if (numOfItems != 0) {
        int* indexPosition = searchKey(value, 0);

        if (indexPosition != nullptr) {
            *indexPosition = -2;
            --numOfItems;
        }
    }
}

void HashTable::resetTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
        ht[i] = -1;
    }

    numOfItems = 0;
}

void HashTable::rehash() {
    int *oldHt = ht;
    int oldCapacity = capacity;
    capacity = (capacity * 2) + 1;
    ht = new int[capacity];
    numOfItems = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
        ht[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < oldCapacity; ++i) {
        if (oldHt[i] != -1 && oldHt[i] != -2) {
            insertKey(oldHt[i]);
        }
    }

    delete[] oldHt;
    oldHt = nullptr;
}

bool HashTable::searchKey(int value) const {
    int j = 0;

    int *indexValue = &ht[hashValue(value, j)];
    int *firstIndexValue = indexValue;
    bool stillSearching = true;
    while (stillSearching) {
        if (*indexValue == value || *indexValue == -1 || (indexValue == firstIndexValue && j != 0)) { // The third or condition is to make sure it has
            stillSearching = false;                                                                 // wrapped around at least one time and 
        }                                                                                          // if it did and landed on first index value again, just stop the search.
        else {
            ++j;
            indexValue = &ht[hashValue(value, j)];
        }
    }

    return (*indexValue == value);
}

int* HashTable::searchKey(int value, int j) const {
    int *indexValue = &ht[hashValue(value, j)];
    int *firstIndexValue = indexValue;
    bool stillSearching = true;

    while (stillSearching) {
        if (*indexValue == value || *indexValue == -1 || (indexValue == firstIndexValue && j != 0)) { // The third or condition is to make sure it has
            stillSearching = false;                                                                 // wrapped around at least one time and 
        }                                                                                          // if it did and landed on first index value again, just stop the search.
        else {
            ++j;
            indexValue = &ht[hashValue(value, j)];
        }
    }

    if (*indexValue != value) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return indexValue;
}

HashTable& HashTable::operator=(const HashTable& otherTable) {
    // Avoid self-assignment by checking that the 
    // parameter passed is not the calling object:
    if (&otherTable != this)
    {
        // If the array we are passing has a different
        // capacity from the calling object,
        // then we need to create a new array:
        if (capacity != otherTable.capacity)
        {
            // Deallocate the memory used by 
            // the calling object and
            // re-create the object so that 
            // it has the same capacity:

            delete[] ht;
            ht = new int[otherTable.capacity];

            // Update capacity:
            capacity = otherTable.capacity;
        }

        // Update number of elements:
        numOfItems = otherTable.numOfItems;

        // Start copying:
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfItems; ++i)
            ht[i] = otherTable.ht[i];
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Attempted assignment to itself.";
    }

    return (*this);
}

HashTable& HashTable::operator=(HashTable&& otherTable) {
    if (this != &otherTable) {
        delete[] ht;
        ht = move(otherTable.ht);
        capacity = move(otherTable.capacity);
        numOfItems = move(otherTable.numOfItems);

        otherTable.ht = nullptr;
        otherTable.capacity = move(0);
        otherTable.numOfItems = move(0);
    }

    return (*this);
}

HashTable::~HashTable() {
    delete[] ht;
    ht = nullptr;   
}
```

Comment: Who told you that the hashtable was an outdated concept? It's one of the two most common approaches to implementing a mapping type and many think it has significant performance benefits over a tree-based approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't use `using` in your headers

Everyone who uses the header will have *the entire contents of the `std` namespace* copied into the global namespace *whether they want them or not*.  It's not what I expect when I write `#include "hashtable.h"`, and it's poor practice to inflict that on your <s>victims</s> users.

---

Otherwise, the code looks pretty clean.  Good use of `const` where appropriate.  Some issues that may be worth looking at:

- Prefer to use a smart pointer rather than a raw pointer for `ht`, which is owned by this class.
- We can use `std::fill` instead of a `for` loop to initialise the contents of `ht`.
- It's probably more convenient to implement move construction/assignment in terms of `swap()`, so implement that.
- Prefer to use the standard names for functions such as `capacity()` and `empty()`, to make this class more interchangeable with the standard collections.  Similarly, consider providing iterators and making the content type a template parameter.
- Test program - do you really need to flush every line of output?  Or can most of those `std::endl` be simply `\n` instead?